# Implicit self in @escaping Closures when Reference Cycles are Unlikely to Occur Swift 5.3

Tags: ios, swift, swift5

With [SE-0269](https://github.com/apple/swift-evolution/blob/master/proposals/0269-implicit-self-explicit-capture.md) we won’t need to use explicit anymore in the below case for reference type.

```
class Test {
    var x = 0
    func execute(_ work: @escaping () -> Void) {
        work()
    }
    func method() {
        execute { [self] in
            x += 1
        }
    }
}
```

Will this handle [weak self] and [unowned self] or we should explicitly use in the case of weak and unowned for this proposal.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You still need to manually specify `weak` and `unowned` captures of `self`. The only change SE-0269 results in is that you don't need to explicitly write out `self.` when accessing instance properties/methods when acknowledging that you capture `self` strongly by using `[self]`.

In case of `[weak self]` you still need to explicitly write `self.` in the closure, but when using `[unowned self]`, you can omit `self.` just as when using `[self]`.

```
execute { [weak self] in
    x += 1 // Error: Reference to property 'x' in closure requires explicit use of 'self' to make capture semantics explicit
}

execute { [weak self] in
    self?.x += 1 // need to manually specify `self?.`
}

execute { [unowned self] in
    x += 1 // compiles fine
}
```